# Using swagger-codegen with username and password basic auth

Tags: django, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a django rest_framework API, Swagger and a Swagger UI.
When I am not logged in I can see a very limited view of "login" and "docs".
When I am logged in I can see lots of stuff.

I am trying to use the swagger-codegen to generate a client:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
generate -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/docs/ -l python -o myclient
```

However, it only generates a very limited client that provides the "login" and "docs" functionality.

How do I let swagger-codegen know how to login using http basic authentication, in order for it to generate a more complete client?

The docs says I should do the following, but I do not know what it expects:

```
    -a <authorization>, --auth <authorization>
        adds authorization headers when fetching the swagger definitions
        remotely. Pass in a URL-encoded string of name:header with a comma
        separating multiple values
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using http basic authentication the command should be:

```
java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar \
generate -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/docs/ -l python -o myclient -a "Authorization:Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l"
```

Where `QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` is your `username:password` encoded in base64.

[Here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/1dd9ee39af6c4e2f9c016a94d16ca47a88a9cb0d/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java#L21) you can have a look at the code that will parse this option.

Comment: You can use [this site](https://www.base64encode.org) to encode the credentials using the following format: `username:password`.

Comment: I found this solution close but not quite correct. As the documentation (confusingly) states and the [source link shows](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/java/io/swagger/codegen/auth/AuthParser.java#L29), in addition to parsing a string for an auth header `key:value` pair via a literal `:` delimiter, it is also expecting the _key and value_ to be UTF-8 URLEncoded. e.g. to pass an `Authorization` header with base64 creds of `admin:admin` (`Basic  YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=`) the final arg should be `-a Authorization:Basic%20YWRtaW46YWRtaW4%3D`

Comment: Surely there must be some way to provide credentials without hard-coding them into the source code generation process. Aside from being insecure, does that mean we need to regenerate and recompile our code if a password changes?

Answer (score 0):

To provide credentials to all requests:

```
var creds = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(creds.UserName + ":" + creds.Password));
            
Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

//use the API
var searchAPI = new SearchAPI();
var files = searchAPI.GetFiles();
```

To provide the credentials to just one API call:

```
var creds = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(creds.UserName + ":" + creds.Password));

var searchAPI = new SearchAPI();
searchAPI.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

//use the API
var files = searchAPI.GetFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a custom authenticator.

```
var basicAuthenticator = new BasicAuthenticator(Configuration.Default.ApiClient.RestClient.BaseUrl.ToString(), "username", "password");
Configuration.Default.ApiClient.RestClient.Authenticator = basicAuthenticator;
```

Which uses the BasicAuthenticator class:

```
public class BasicAuthenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    private readonly string _baseUrl;
    private readonly string _userName;
    private readonly string _password;
    private readonly CredentialCache _credentialCache;

    public BasicAuthenticator(string baseUrl, string userName, string password)
    {
        _baseUrl = baseUrl;
        _userName = userName;
        _password = password;

        _credentialCache = new CredentialCache
        {
            {new Uri(_baseUrl), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password)}
        };
    }

    public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
    {
        request.Credentials = _credentialCache;

        if (request.Parameters.Any(parameter =>
                        parameter.Name.Equals("Authorization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            return;
        }
        request.AddParameter("Authorization", GetBasicAuthHeaderValue(), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
    }


    private string GetBasicAuthHeaderValue()
    {
        return string.Format("Basic {0}",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            _userName, _password))));
    }
}
```

There's a [known issue](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/414) with RestSharp that it won't provide the Basic Auth details to second request (after a redirect). Using the above authenticator resolves that.